# How to analyze the Plutus budget usage?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutustx

When I run my minting policy script I get the error

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for policyId 0 (in the order of the PolicyIds) failed with:
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The machine terminated part way through evaluation due to overspending the budget.
The budget when the machine terminated was:
({ cpu: 5735219989
| mem: -56
})
```

Is there any way to catch what is the cause of memory overflow/leak?

Comment: Have you looked at https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howtos/profiling-scripts.html?